# How to declare custom error exchange for each consumer in EasyNetQ?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, consumer, easynetq

I have four consumer when error  occured message publishing to default  EasyNetQ_Default_Error_Queue is it possible to each queue consumer write own error exchange

For example;

```
Queue Name : A    ErrorExchange :A_ErrorExchange
Queue Name : B    ErrorExchange :B_ErrorExchange
```

---

```
bus.Advanced.Conventions.ErrorExchangeNamingConvention = new ErrorExchangeNameConvention(info => "A_DeadLetter");

bus.Advanced.Conventions.ErrorExchangeNamingConvention = new ErrorExchangeNameConvention(info2 => "B_DeadLetter");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the code you've provided, it looks like you're almost there -- you just need to override `ErrorExchangeNamingConvention` and `ErrorQueueNamingConvention` appropriately.

As an example, here's a method that will return an instance of `IBus` with these conventions overridden to incorporate the specified consumer name:

```
public IBus CreateBus(string connectionString, string consumerName) 
{
    var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connectionString);

    // Modify the following to create your error exchange name appropriately
    bus.Advanced.Container.Resolve<IConventions>().ErrorExchangeNamingConvention = 
        info => consumerName + "_ErrorExchange";

    // Modify the following to create your error queue name appropriately
    bus.Advanced.Container.Resolve<IConventions>().ErrorQueueNamingConvention = 
        () => consumerName + "_ErrorQueue";

    return bus;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as per EasyNetQ 6.3.1, ErrorExchangeNamingConvention  and ErrorQueueNamingConvention are both changed to read-only :(
and the naming convention has to be injected during bus creation.